# Change CSS when user is logged in

Tags: css

So I have the following code:

```
        <h3>
             <div class="sellertitle"><a class="allseller" href="#">Something</a> </div>

             <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>          
                     <div class="otherseller">  <a class="allotherseller" href="#">Else</a> </div>
             <?php } ?>
        </h3>
```

Then, for the "sellertitle," I have the following CSS:

```
<--logged in-->
.sellertitle {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;      
}
```

As you can see, "Something" is always visible and "Else" is only visible when the user is logged in.

However when the user is logged out, I want the "sellertitle" CSS to be "float:none"

```
<--logged out-->
  .sellertitle {
   float: none;
   width: 49%;      
 }
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is another CSS-only approach, without any inline-PHP and needless CSS-spam in the head.
If your theme is correctly using [body_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) and a user is logged in, Wordpress adds a class "logged-in" to the body-element, so we can use this in our stylesheet:

```
<--logged out-->
.sellertitle {
  float: none;
  width: 49%;      
}

.otherseller {
  display: none;
}

<--logged in-->
.logged-in .sellertitle {
  float: left;     
}

.logged-in .otherseller {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Smart approach. Use what is already there by default :-). +1

Comment: I would add that this answer needs that the theme correctly use `body_class()` function, just for users who don't know about it. +1.

Comment: @cybmeta indeed,you are right... in most cases I'm using _s as a base for my themes, which sets `body_class()` by default :)

Comment: ha! another one added to my "aha!" moment.. this should be marked as the answer. :)

Comment: Awesome approach. I am going to try this.:-) I thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

you could try something like this... this will add css on the head

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_css_head');
function add_css_head() {
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   ?>
      <style>
          .sellertitle {
             float: left;
             width: 49%;      
           }
      </style>
   <?php
   } else {
   ?>
      <style>
          .sellertitle {
             float: none;
             width: 49%;      
           }
      </style>
   <?php
   }
}
```

---

another is to change class if logged in...

so you will have two css

```
.sellertitle {
  float: none;
  width: 49%;      
}
.sellertitle.logged {
  float: left;      
}
```

then on your div something like this...

```
<div class="sellertitle <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {echo 'logged';}">
```

Comment: added another option... and I think is best approach.. ;)

Comment: I see. That's something I never tried. Thanks for the info! =)

Comment: Not really smart adding styles directly to `wp_head`. Create a custom stylesheet and use `wp_enqueue_scripts` to load your custom stylesheet. This way, plugins and child themes can override these styles if needed with ease. Also, check out the other answer which uses what is given by default :-)